# Search date range mongodb: Recursion Exception

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, fastapi

I'm writing an api to interface with a mongodb, however when trying to filter based on dates I'm getting the following error:

```
File "/shares/dev/mongo_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 43, in jsonable_encoder
    if isinstance(obj, BaseModel):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/abc.py", line 98, in __instancecheck__
    return _abc_instancecheck(cls, instance)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
@app.post('/search/')
def search_post(vendor: str = '', program: str = '', severity: str = '', _from: str = "", to: str = ""):
    # TODO: Add search options: Program/Vender/(Date-Range)
    data = {}
    if vendor:
        data['vendor'] = vendor
    if program:
        data['program'] = program
    if severity:
        data['severity'] = severity
    if _from:
        _from = utils.convert_date_string(_from)
    if to:
        to = utils.convert_date_string(to)

    my_data = MyData.objects().filter((Q(mod_date__gte=_from) & Q(mod_date__lte=to)))
    return my_data
```

I'm using mongoengine to interface with the database.

Comment: The recursion is not happening in your `search_post` endpoint, it's happening in fastapi's  jsonable_encoder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I am an idiot, but here is the answer for anyone who runs into the same issue.

```
my_data = MyData.objects().filter((Q(mod_date__gte=_from) & Q(mod_date__lte=to)))
```

Needs to be converted to a list of dicts before passing it back to fastapi

```
return list(my_data)
```

fixed the issue